# Illustrations of a line and a curve intersecting for complex field

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-geometry, visualization

Are there nice illustrations on the Net of say $y=a·x+b$ and $y=x^2$ intersecting where x and y are complex? I'm thinking of the amplitude of y being depicted as height above the complex plane with phase color coded or assigned a vector at that height, for example.

I'm interested in seeing a depiction of the two "surfaces" representing the complex curves intersecting, not just the intersection points.

Comment: http://www.math.purdue.edu/~dvb/graph/algcurve.html